# Rank and Nullity of Matrix with Arbitrary Parameters

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Given the matrix A defined as A =
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -4 & 4 & -2 \\
6 & a-2 & 7 & a-6 \\
-1 & 2-b & 8 & -b+1 \\
\end{bmatrix}

where (a) and (b) are real constants, I am interested in finding the rank and nullity of (A). Applying the normal Reduced Row Echelon Form (RREF) method, I obtained a matrix R equivalent to R = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}

yielding a rank of 3 and a nullity of 1 for (A).

My question is whether this approach directly applies despite the presence of parameters (a) and (b). Specifically, is it necessary to consider different cases based on the values of (a) and (b) (e.g., (a = 0), (b = 0), (a ≠ 0), (b ≠ 0)) to accurately determine the rank and nullity, or can the RREF result be used universally for any real values of (a) and (b)?

Comment: How did you remove $a$ and $b$ when RREF if you dont know their value and each parameter only shows up in a single row?